# ServerSocketChannel or Endpoint

Tags: java, serversocket, endpoint

What is better in regards of performance. Java ServerSocketChannel or java endpoint? I want to create a simple multiplayer game? Can you create asynchronous communication with endpoint in java?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which endpoint you mean but `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` is usually used for `SOAP` services. If you want to make a multiplayer game with acceptable latency and low memory footprint - so many clients can connect - your best bet is `NIO` (`ServerSocketChannel`) + some specific pattern called "Reactor". This one is hard to implement so you should better use this framework (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_%28software%29). Nevertheless, if the game is simple, you could stick to plain `Socket` and `ServerSocket`, which is much easier and works in the same way as Channels (in terms of result).

Comment: I already created asynchronous ServerSocketChannel and works very good. I am just curious about new Java EE Endpoint which communicate over Session remote call. I see that many people have some problems with remote session inside Endpoint but nobody talk about performance. So far I just worked with java ServerSocket and java ServerSocketChannel I will also try this Netty TCP and test performance.

Comment: Yes "Endpoint" I thought javax.xml.ws.Endpoint or WebSocket in Java EE7 http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm

Comment: Ok then Endpoint does not make much sense for multiplayer that is only for EE applications for SOAP?

Comment: Generally speaking, it does not. Unless you want to make your backend a full fledged java EE server. Which is possible. But beware, java EE is not really used for game applications (only its parts). In terms of network connections, I think, most of the games a made over simple blocking/non-blocking socket classes. Not much of services.